# How to get excel cell color in java

Tags: xssf

I have an **XSLX** sheet in which few cells are having background color Green, few Red and rest are default(white).

How to identify the cell color ? based on the cell color, i have to process the text in the cell. I am using apache poi.

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(6);
CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
Color cellColor = (cell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor());
```

if the cellColor will hold the background color of the cell, how can the color name be retrevied from it.

Please Help

thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 2):

Don't base it on text value.  You're almost there.

```
Color cellColor = (cell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColorColor());
```

Now just do:

```
if(cellColor.equals(Color.GREEN)) {
  //do whatever
}
```